# \subsection{...}-result in line with following text

Tags: sectioning

Hello this is my first question here.

Normally, if I write something like

```
\subsection*{a)}
 blabla
```

it is displaid like

**a)**
blabla

Now I want to achieve that this two elements are inline like

**a)** blabla

Is this possible?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) how `\subsection` is formatted depends on what document class you are using.  a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be helpful here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section*{This is a section}
\subsection*{This is a subsection}
\subsubsection*{This is a subsubsection}
\paragraph{This} is a paragraph.
\subparagraph{This} is a subparagraph.
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image: Section and Paragraph levels]

You can also number them by setting `secnumdepth` to 4 or 5.

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
```

Or you could use a 'numbered' list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\bfseries\alph{enumi})}
    \item \lipsum[2]
    \item \lipsum[3]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image: Alphabetized List]

Comment: But if the following text is longer than that first line, how to I achieve that the next line is aligned with the "start" of the text itself and not under the "paragraph counter"?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a list in the format I think you want. It makes use of a [numbered list](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures).

Comment: Great, that is indeed exactly what I want. Thank you!

Comment: AMS style guide says that subsection headings should be bold with the text of the following paragraph continuing in line.  Subsubsection headings should be italic with the paragraph following in line